# Using XFreeRDP, is it possible to view active sessions before logging in?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, remote-desktop

In my office we have several machines that everyone log in to for a certain resources, using 5 global users anyone can access.(sadly they did not agree to change to process so i have to adjust) - if i use xfreerdp to log in with FFA_BOB1, and he is logged in, i kick him out - this happens every day for many people.

Is it possible, using XfreeRDP to see the active sessions BEFORE logging in? either with CLI or even by viewing the RDP Welcome screen? that was we can all check before kicking each other out until this backwards process is changed.

I'm using 2.0.0-rc4.
I tried

```
-authentication
```

which doesn't work, it just tries to log in with "root" user

Comment: (Active) sessions are created **after** login.

Comment: I mean, since this is a server, and multiple people can log in. sometimes there are 4-5 people already logged in, and if you log in as well with the same user you kick them. as seen here for example "https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/user-accounts-family-safety/197501d1532813708t-how-make-windows-10-login-screen-display-users-signed-loggedusers.jpg"